# how to get the path with trailing pathseparator in c++ using boost

Tags: c++, boost, path-separator

I have a path such as this:

```
boost::filesystem::path mypath("c:/test");
boost::filesystem::path mypath1("c:/test/);
```

I want to make sure that when I convert them to string, both of them appears as :

```
c:/test/
```

for example if I do:

```
cout<<mypath.string()<<endl;
cout<<mypath1.string()<<endl;
```

both of them print out:

```
c:/test/
```

How can I do this in c++ using boost?

Comment: I don't think any of the standard functions in the file system library supports what you are after, it will always tread `C:/test` as a file and `C:/test/` as a directory - until you check it.. Your best bet would be to convert to string and check if it ends with a path separator and if not, add it to the string!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a builtin function.

You could use this, though:

```
if ("." != p.filename()) 
   p += fs::path::preferred_separator;
```

> This will not add the separator if the path ends in `/.`

Optionally, call `p.remove_trailing_separator` first, but that will also remove any trailing double-slash if it was part of the input (some applications treat this as having significant meaning).

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d47a144370a5afa)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for (std::string s : boost::make_iterator_range(argv+1, argv+argc)) {
        fs::path p = s;
        //p.remove_trailing_separator();
        if ("." != p.filename())
            p += fs::path::preferred_separator;

        std::cout << "'" << s << "'\t" << p << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints (on linux, obviously):

```
'.' "."
''  "/"
'/' "//"
'/tmp'  "/tmp/"
'/tmp/' "/tmp/"
'/tmp//'    "/tmp//"
'/tmp/.'    "/tmp/."
'/tmp/..'   "/tmp/../"
'/tmp/...'  "/tmp/.../"
'/tmp/aa.txt'   "/tmp/aa.txt/"
'c:\test.txt'   "c:\test.txt/"
```

Comment: why you excludes "." but not "" ?

Comment: @sercxjo Actually, I don't remember. I think `""` is just a bad example - it's not a valid path and it would be unsafe to assume it means `"/"`. So I'd rather suggest to input validate that `""` is not valid input and always leave a trailing /, including `"./"`. To be completely honest, I think the real problem is that it is pretty unclear why the output format matters to OP (to me `/some/path/./` doesn't make more sense than `/some/path/.`. My examples were chosen to reflect how weird the requirement works out, see the last entries)

Comment: @sercxjo Ah. I (and you) should just have tried it out. The comment in the answer explained it: _"This will not add the separator if the path ends in /."_, compare: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb04270976fd76f6